# How to update LV UUID, Devices file not found

Tags: linux, lvm

A recent BIOS update has jumbled things in my LVM but I'm not sure what...

```
[root@localhost ~]# pvscan
  Devices file sys_wwid naa.57c35481cc13b195 PVID IpYMVDa5eXTqYQuLzXc8GukoAVUOK32u last seen on /dev/sda3 not found.
  No matching physical volumes found
```

I get the same output from: vgscan & lvscan.

```
[root@localhost ~]# lsblk -f
NAME                FSTYPE      FSVER    LABEL UUID                                   FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
sda
├─sda1              vfat        FAT16    EFI   851C-90D9                               492.7M     1% /boot/efi
├─sda2              ext4        1.0      BOOT  eb88de2a-850c-431a-a05b-5f133879aee9      100M    72% /boot
└─sda3              LVM2_member LVM2 001       IpYMVD-a5eX-TqYQ-uLzX-c8Gu-koAV-UOK32u
  ├─rl_localhost-swap swap        1        SWAP  43082c91-a0ec-4f86-a776-1457ac39ba6f                  [SWAP]
  └─rl_localhost-root ext4        1.0      ROOT  9c40db8f-7185-48a6-a188-be13a4724ea9     37.9G    16% /
```

listing the contents of /dev/mapper:

```
[root@localhost dev]# ls -All mapper/
total 0
crw-------. 1 root root 10, 236 May  8 03:22 control
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root       7 May  8 03:22 rl_localhost-root -> ../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root       7 May  8 03:22 rl_localhost-swap -> ../dm-0
```

I believe these dm-# files are the 'Devices files' from the warning/error message. Could use some explanation here:  /dev/sda3 is the LV that contains the root partition and the swap partition.  How and or why is it there are 'devices files (dm-0, dm-1)' for the root and swap partitions, but then the LV sda doesn't have/needs a 'devices file'(?)

```
[root@localhost dev]# blkid
/dev/mapper/rl_localhost-root: LABEL="ROOT" UUID="9c40db8f-7185-48a6-a188-be13a4724ea9" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/rl_localhost-swap: LABEL="SWAP" UUID="43082c91-a0ec-4f86-a776-1457ac39ba6f" TYPE="swap"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="BOOT" UUID="eb88de2a-850c-431a-a05b-5f133879aee9" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="9072cb02-0943-43a2-8718-cc67983eebd4"
/dev/sda3: UUID="IpYMVD-a5eX-TqYQ-uLzX-c8Gu-koAV-UOK32u" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="9daab51d-ec9d-443c-bcd6-146e0a7bcd4a"
/dev/sda1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL_FATBOOT="EFI" LABEL="EFI" UUID="851C-90D9" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="d7833ebe-ab1a-47b8-9fc8-8625374b6998"
```

the above is another point of confusion. blkid shows /dev/sda with UUID same as lsblk, but maybe that is confusing because I'm not sure what I'm looking for.

**Update**

So, I didn't fix the root cause of the issue yet, but I did find a work around for it with my test criteria being the following:

With the missing 'Devices file', I could not execute such things as:

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/rocky/grub.cfg
```

issuing the above command would fail with the:

```
 Devices file sys_wwid naa.57c35481cc13b195 PVID IpYMVDa5eXTqYQuLzXc8GukoAVUOK32u last seen on /dev/sda3 not found.
```

I located LVM's Devices file here:`/etc/lvm/devices/system.devices`. I renamed it to .bak. Now the above command does not fail.  I was reading through the man page [enter link description here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lvmdevices.8.html), and looking over the 4th paragraph in the description indicates that LVM will fall back to using device names if the specific HW info is unavailable.  I'm guess this is what is happening since the system is still bootable and operating which also having this problem.

So, have a work around but still unsure how to correct the now faulty hardware identification data for the disk in lvm. any ideas?

Comment: I am seeing the same error message after upgrading from Rocky Linux 9.1 to 9.2 in a virtual machine. I end up in emergency recovery mode with it not finding the /home LVM paritition (it finds the root and swap LVM partitions). Renaming the system.devices file did fix that and gave me the /home partition back.

Answer (score 0):

First rename back the system.devices file, then run this command:

```
lvmdevices --deldev /dev/sda3
```

Check if the command deleted the wrong entry:

```
lvmdevices
```

If nothing is given back, run the pvscan command to get the new PV device, then:

```
lvmdevices --adddev /dev/sdXY
```

If everything is good, the system is now usable. You can re-run the grub2-mkconfig and also a clean boot will be good for testing.